# Finding XML elements by type and ID in node.js

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, express

I'm kinda new to node.js and really new to using it with XML. I can't figure out how to find a specific element in a XML document based on the element's ID and type.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is handle requests with Express and then using a value from a query string in the request, search for an element in a XML document and send the contents of that element back as the response.

Here's some of my code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    xmlDoc = require('document.xml'),
    app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    var id = req.query.id;
    /* Here's where I want to get the element from xmlDoc based on id and element type*/
    res.send(/* Send the contents of the element */)
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[xmldom](https://www.npmjs.org/package/xmldom) provides an implementation of the DOM Api for node.js

```
var DOMParser = new (require('xmldom')).DOMParser;
var document = DOMParser.parseFromString(xmlString);

var nodeById = document.getElementById('someId');
var nodesByName = document.getElementsByTagName('someName');
```

If you need more flexibility check out [xpath](https://www.npmjs.org/package/xpath).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some XML parser like [libxmljs](https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs), [xmldoc](https://github.com/nfarina/xmldoc) or [node-xml2js](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js) which is a XML to JS object converter.